# Printing an ArrayList while reading it for print conditions

Tags: java, loops, printing, arraylist, anagram

I have two `ArrayList<String>`s. One contains words with punctuation and capitalization, the other has these removed.

List1:

```
File word: it's
File word: Sit
File word: yes-man
File word: murdered
File word: ok
File word: DereDrum
File word: Hello
File word: Friend
```

List2:

```
Edited word: its
Edited word: sit
Edited word: yesman
Edited word: murdered
Edited word: ok
Edited word: deredrum
Edited word: hello
Edited word: friend
```

The idea was to check and see which words are anagrams of each other. If they were, all I want to do is reprint them, but with the words that are anagrams on the same line as each other:

```
it's Sit

yes-man

murdered DereDrum

ok

hello

friend
```

I tried to do this like so:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.print(words.get(i));
            for (int j = i+1; j < grams.size(); j++)
            {
                anagramChecker(grams.get(i),"",grams.get(j),words.get(j));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

The way I had it in mind was that this for loop lasts for the size of the List1(words) and prints the word it's looking at. Then I use my anagramChecker:

```
public static void anagramChecker(String s1,String s2,String checked,String word)
{
    if(s1.length() == 0)
    {
        if(s2.equals(checked))
        {
            System.out.println(" " + word);
            return;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < s1.length() ; i++)
    {
        anagramChecker(s1.substring(0, i) + s1.substring(i+1, s1.length()),s2 + s1.charAt(i),checked,word);
    }
}
```

This method did not work and it's output was something like this:

```
it's
Sit yes-man
 yes-man
 yes-man
 yes-man
 yes-man
 yes-man
 yes-man
 yes-man

yes-man
murdered
ok
DereDrum Hello

Hello
Friend
```

I tried using a map so I could sort the words alphabetically after the words themselves were sorted alphabetically in the second list. That had about the same looking output.

Comment: For anagram checking don't use recursion. Copy each string to a `char[]`, ***sort*** the array, then do a simple string compare.  Obviously, check for equal length first.

Comment: @Jim Garrison If I do this, the first ArrayList does not get sorted with the second ArrayList. Since I am trying to print the results of the first as though they were done like the second, I'm not sure this would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it again... and someone else has already told you the key points.
Put it to char array, sort it, compare it, done.

```
package array;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Anagrams {

    private static ArrayList<Character> convert(String txt) {
    ArrayList<Character> alph = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (int i = 0; i < txt.length(); i++)
        if (Character.isLetter(txt.charAt(i)))
        alph.add(Character.toLowerCase(txt.charAt(i)));
    Collections.sort(alph);
    return alph;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> first = new ArrayList<String>();
    first.add("it's");
    first.add("Sit");
    first.add("yes-man");
    first.add("murdered");
    first.add("ok");
    first.add("DereDrum");
    first.add("Hello");
    first.add("Friend");

    ArrayList<String> second = new ArrayList<String>();
    second.add("its");
    second.add("sit");
    second.add("yesman");
    second.add("murdered");
    second.add("ok");
    second.add("deredrum");
    second.add("hello");
    second.add("friend");

    ArrayList<Integer> checked = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < first.size(); i++) {
        String line = "";
        if (!checked.contains(i))
        line += first.get(i) + " ";

        ArrayList<Character> firstChrAry = convert(first.get(i));

        for (int j = i + 1; j < second.size(); j++) {
        ArrayList<Character> secondChrAry = convert(second.get(j));
        if (firstChrAry.size() == secondChrAry.size()) {
            if (firstChrAry.equals(secondChrAry)) {
            line += first.get(j);
            checked.add(j);
            }
        }
        }
        if (!line.equals(""))
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    }
}
```

Add my output results here:

it's Sit

yes-man

murdered DereDrum

ok

Hello

Friend

Comment: Took me awhile to understand the code, but I now understand the code! I was so far off with what I had, yet so close. This has cleared it up for me superbly. I cannot thank you enough. I was almost at my wits end but this really puts the use of things like Private Lists into perspective. Thank you, thank you, thank you. I am very close now to my finished program.

Answer (score 2):

Re-using the anagram logic from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1704).

```
public boolean areAnagrams(String s1, String s2) {
    //TODO : Strip punctuations from s1 and s2
    char[] ch1 = s1.toCharArray();
    char[] ch2 = s2.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(ch1);
    Arrays.sort(ch2);
    return Arrays.equals(ch1,ch2);
}
```

Iterate through both lists and check for `areAnagrams` true and then print out.

```
for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {  
    String first = firstList.get(i);
    String second = secondList.get(i);
    if (areAnagrams (first, second) {
        System.out.println(first + " " + second);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. With the help of everyone here I was able to get this portion of my code complete.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> lst1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> lst2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        lst1.add("it's");
        lst1.add("Sit");
        lst1.add("yes-man");
        lst1.add("murdered");
        lst1.add("ok");
        lst1.add("DereDrum");
        lst1.add("Hello");
        lst1.add("Friend");

        lst2.add("its");
        lst2.add("sit");
        lst2.add("yesman");
        lst2.add("murdered");
        lst2.add("ok");
        lst2.add("deredrum");
        lst2.add("hello");
        lst2.add("friend");

        for (int i = 0; i < lst2.size(); i++) {
            String original = lst2.get(i);
            StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer(original);
            buff.reverse();
            if (lst2.contains(buff.toString())) {
                System.out.println(lst1.get(i) + " "
                        + lst1.get(lst2.indexOf(buff.toString())));
                lst1.remove(lst2.indexOf(buff.toString()));
                lst2.remove(buff.toString());
            } else {
                System.out.println(lst1.get(i));
            }

        }

    }

}
```

And output would be.

```
it's
Sit
yes-man
murdered DereDrum
ok
Hello
Friend
```

You can run and check online by clicking below link.

[Example Java Online Running Fiddle](http://ideone.com/g3wMzM)

Comment: Only thing is this does not recognize it's and sit to be anagrams, but they are.

Comment: `its` and `sit` are not anagram. anagram of `its` is `sti`

Comment: An anagram is not the word reversed. An anagram is a word with the same amount of letters in it and they all share the same number of letters.